# ibase_query with calculations on query but return whole number instead of decimal

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.1

I have a query on PHP using ibase and when I try it on firebird using isql it returns decimal but when I try it in PHP it return whole numbers.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT FIRST 4 FISCALYEAR, FISCALQTR, SUM(COALESCE(REJECTS,0)) TOTALREJECTS, 
    SUM(COALESCE(GOODQTY,0)) GOOD, SUM(COALESCE(TESTED,0)) TOTALTESTED,
    ROUND((1-(SUM(COALESCE(REJECTCOUNT,0))/SUM(COALESCE(ITEMCOUNT,0)))),3)
    COUNTAVG
FROM SAMPLETABLE
GROUP BY FISCALYEAR, FISCALQTR
ORDER BY FISCALYEAR DESC, FISCALQTR DESC
```

Note: `COUNTAVG` return in `isql` 0.9786 while in PHP ibase it return 1 only.
please help.

Comment: Your question seems unclear; are you trying to figure out a reason why it's an integer instead of a decimal number, or are you trying to get to the decimal number instead of the integer?

Comment: Thanks for the response Bernard, but I already solved my problem. I just only need to specify the dialect of my database when connecting to firebird using ibase_connect.

Comment: Good to hear! Don't hesitate to answer your own question. :)

Comment: Very likely you are using a database that is dialect 1 (which is essentially deprecated) and were connecting using dialect 3 where integer division will have an integer result.

Comment: You are right Mark, I think the default dialect of php is the highest one supported by client libraries that is why its returning integer result.